# Return image if id is not found or equal null

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Im getting the previous id with the code below but when it reaches the last id it returns null because there is no more ids to show. How can I return an image? My brain is too tired to figure it out at this time. I know is something simple but I can’t think :) Thank you in advance.

`

```
Post 
       .findOne({"_id" : {"$lt" : id}})
       .sort({"_id" : -1})
       .limit(1).exec(function(err, previousPost) {                      
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        if(!previousPost){
           //?????
        }
```

`

Comment: please describe your use case , how you are using this , what is to be displayed  ?

Comment: previousPost returns an object which is being display to the user as a post with all its fields (title, post body, date, etc.) id is coming from req.params.id (post that is currently displaying)

Comment: ok , id you pass when it is last post ?

Comment: id is coming from req.params.id. previousPost give me the preview object on the collection based on the current object id that is being display.

Comment: I fixed the issue using conditions on client side with EJS

<% if (previousPost !== null) { %> 
 Show object
<% } else { %>
Show something else
<% } %>